# Hash Map with key Values - How to get the value using bigdecimal key?

Tags: java, oracle

Hash Map with key Values. How to get the value using bigdecimal key?

month_id.intValue() . this is not working

public String getMonthNameById(BigDecimal month_id)   {

```
    String monthName = "";

        Map<Integer, String> months = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        months.put(1, "January");

        months.put(2, "February");

        months.put(3, "March");

        months.put(4, "April");

        months.put(5, "May");

        months.put(6, "June");

        months.put(7, "July");

        months.put(8, "August");

        months.put(9, "September");

        months.put(10, "October");


        months.put(11, "November");

        months.put(12, "December");


        monthName = (String)months.get(month_id.intValue());

        return monthName;
}
```

Comment: Um... What? Make your question more clear. Where do you declare your hashmap?

Comment: @Kyranstar  Map<Integer, String> months = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

Comment: @Kyranstar   public String getMonthNameById(BigDecimal month_id){
  String monthName = "";
      Map<Integer, String> months = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
   months.put(1, "January");
   months.put(2, "February");
   months.put(3, "March");
   months.put(4, "April");
   months.put(5, "May");
   months.put(6, "June");
   months.put(7, "July");
   months.put(8, "August");
   months.put(9, "September");
   months.put(10, "October");
   months.put(11, "November");
   months.put(12, "December");
   
   monthName = (String)months.get(month_id.intValue());
   
   return monthName;
 }

Comment: Holy cow man, don't put that in the comments section. It's a mess that no one wants to read. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can guess what you might be doing, I came up with this and it is working. Please have a look:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal myBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(11);
        Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        myMap.put(new Integer(11), "Hello World!");
        String message = (String) myMap.get(myBigDecimal.intValue());
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE\classes>java MyTest
Hello World!
```